# Implement Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a generic interface, looking like this

```
public interface IDataReader<T> where T:class
{
    IQueryable<T> ReadFile(DataTable table);
}
```

and I want to create a class that implement this interface.
Is it possible that we actually create a class that using real class instead of generic like the interface ?

```
public class CustomnReader<Person> : IDataReader<T>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean `public class CustomnReader<Person> : IDataReader<Person>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do like this

```
public class CustomnReader<Person> : IDataReader<T> // <- Here you must give an exact class

public class CustomnReader<Person> : IDataReader<Person> // Like this
```

or you can do

```
 public class CustomnReader<T> : IDataReader<T> where T : class // <- Here create and give a type when creating an object

CustomerReader<Person> cr = new CustomerReader<Person>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuval and Suren,

I end up using

```
public class CustomnReader : IDataReader<Person>
```

it looks like it can work as for now.

Thank you